# Is there any difference between double-click the window's title bar and click the window's maximize button?

Tags: graphics, directx-12, imgui

I find a pretty weird bug while using the imgui dx12 example. When I double-click the window's title bar to maximize the window, the program failed in recreating the command allocator. But click the window's maximize button or resize the window is ok. The graphics driver might cause this problem, because it only happens when I run the program with the integrated intel graphics card.

Comment: imgui is a concept not a product. Clarify what you are actually using.  For example the term may refer to IMGUI mode in Unity or the open-source product ImGui (both capitalised in the way I have written).  Either way a question without code is likely to get closed or down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

At the Win32 API level, double-clicking on the non-client area (the title bar) causes a [WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nclbuttondblclk), whilst the maximise/resize will cause a [WM_SYSCOMMAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand).

If neither is processed by the client, the system will perform default behaviour and issue a [WM_SIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-size) to inform of the action.

What ImGui does with these events I cannot tell you.